# Counting Hours in Date

Tags: excel, vba

I have a list of records with date time stamps. I want to count all records that were stamped at 6 AM. When I use "=Hour(A1)" for my value in A1 "6/18/2019  6:05:00 AM" Excel returns "6".

How can I count all my records for 6 AM in column A?

I have tried:

```
=COUNTIF(A:A,HOUR(6))
```

But Excel returns "0".

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easily doable with `SUMPRODUCT`, e.g.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(HOUR(A1:A20)=6))
```

[image]

Comment: I just tried this formula and I get a "#VALUE!". Do you know I'm getting this result?

Comment: Are you sure everything in your range is a true date?

Comment: When I try "=SUMPRODUCT(--(HOUR(A:A)=6))" I get an error.

But when I try "=SUMPRODUCT(--(HOUR(A2:A15)=6))" I get my result.
Is there a way I can do this for the whole column? Or would I just set my range as ("A2:A1000")?

Comment: Do you have a header in the column? The latter seems like an easy option.

Comment: Yes, I have a header in the column. I just tested the formula after removing the header and it works. You sir are a genius!

Comment: Thanks for the compliment, glad to help.

Comment: Do you know how I can add a second criteria from another column? I want to count all records that are from 6 AM and have a "Rejected" in column B.

Comment: Yep, something like `=SUMPRODUCT((HOUR(A2:A20)=6)*(B2:B20="Rejected"))`